# Implement swipe action within current code of actionbar tabs, fragments

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, android-actionbar, swipe

I have searched high and low to find the answer. Some great resources out there, but none that I found that I could incorporate into my code currently. However, I am a beginner aka noob in java/android programming so that could be the issues haha. I have the following working code.  Each tab has a class associated with it. Four Tabs, Four classes plus the xml to go along with each tab/class. I implement actionbar, fragments in this code. 
I want to implement horizontal swiping action. I also want to  be able to click on the tabs as well as swipe between them. Can someone help me to  get this done in my existing code? Find me a good tutorial to help? Let me know if my current code could be corrected or improved upon to make this happen? If you need more information let me know. 
Here is the code
Thanks in advance!

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAB_KEY_INDEX = "tab_key";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab mActivityATab = actionbar.newTab().setText(
            getString(R.string.ui_tabname_a));
    ActionBar.Tab mActivityBTab = actionbar.newTab().setText(
            getString(R.string.ui_tabname_b));
    ActionBar.Tab mActivityCTab = actionbar.newTab().setText(
            getString(R.string.ui_tabname_c));
    ActionBar.Tab mActivityDTab = actionbar.newTab().setText(
            getString(R.string.ui_tabname_d));

    Fragment mActivityA = new ActivityA();
    Fragment mActivityB = new ActivityB();
    Fragment mActivityC = new ActivityC();
    Fragment mActivityD = new ActivityD();

    mActivityATab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mActivityA,
            getApplicationContext()));
    mActivityBTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mActivityB,
            getApplicationContext()));
    mActivityCTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mActivityC,
            getApplicationContext()));
    mActivityDTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(mActivityD,
            getApplicationContext()));

    actionbar.addTab(mActivityATab);
    actionbar.addTab(mActivityBTab);
    actionbar.addTab(mActivityCTab);
    actionbar.addTab(mActivityDTab);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(
                TAB_KEY_INDEX, 0));
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

      case R.id.menuitem_quit:

            finish();
            return true;

    }

    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putInt(TAB_KEY_INDEX, getActionBar()
            .getSelectedNavigationIndex());

}

class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public Fragment fragment;
    public Context context;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment, Context context) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

}

}
```

AcivityA(the rest of the classes are the same)

```
public class ActivityA extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activitya, container, false);


}}
```

Comment: I got this to work implementing ABS but would still like to learn how to do it this way as well, for learning purposes.